# Could it be the touch of two fingers on the screen call handlePan method?

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a problem with My code , I need to handle pan or pinch on screen.

but sometimes the handlePanl method call when My two finger on screen.

What Am I doing wrong ?

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizer
{
// handle Pinch
imageViewForCrop.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *PinchOnScreen = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[imageViewForCrop addGestureRecognizer:PinchOnScreen];

// handle Pan
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panOnScreen = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[imageViewForCrop addGestureRecognizer:panOnScreen];


}
```

This is Pan method :

```
 -(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{




switch (recognizer.state)

{

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

    {
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)recognizer.numberOfTouches);

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:imageViewForCrop];



        if (image.size.width > image.size.height) // weight image

        {
            // after user pinch in the screen
            if (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height > self.view.frame.size.height - bottomImageCropView.frame.size.height)

                                {


                                    // allow dragging only in Y coordinates by only updating the Y coordenates with translation position

                                    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);



                                    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:imageViewForCrop];



                                    // get the top edge coordinate for the top left corner of crop frame

                                    float topEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMinY(imageViewForCrop.frame);

                                    float topEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMinY(cropErea.frame);



                                    //get the buttom edge coordinate for bottom left corner of crop frame

                                    float bottomEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMaxY(imageViewForCrop.frame);

                                    float bottomEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMaxY(cropErea.frame);

                                    //

                                    // if the top edge coordinate is less than or equal to Crop Erea frame

                                    if (topEdgeImagePosition > topEdgeCropEreaPosition)

                                    {

                                        // draw drag view in max top position

                                        imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x,topEdgeCropEreaPosition,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

                                    }

                                    // if bottom edge coordinate is greater than or equal to 480

                                    if (bottomEdgeImagePosition < bottomEdgeCropEreaPosition)

                                    {

                                        float ratio = (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height - cropErea.frame.size.height) * -1;

                                        // draw drag view in max bottom position

                                        imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x,ratio,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

                                    }


                                }




            // allow dragging only in X coordinates by only updating the X coordenates with translation position

            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y);

            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:imageViewForCrop];



            // get the top edge coordinate for the top left corner of crop frame

            float leftEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMinX(imageViewForCrop.frame);

            float leftEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMinX(cropErea.frame);



            //get the buttom edge coordinate for bottom left corner of crop frame

            float rightEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMaxX(imageViewForCrop.frame);

            float rightEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMaxX(cropErea.frame);

            //

            // if the top edge coordinate is less than or equal to Crop Erea frame

            if (leftEdgeImagePosition > leftEdgeCropEreaPosition)

            {

                // draw drag view in max top position

                imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(leftEdgeCropEreaPosition,0,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

            }

            // if bottom edge coordinate is greater than or equal to 480

            if (rightEdgeImagePosition < rightEdgeCropEreaPosition)

            {

                float ratio = (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width - cropErea.frame.size.width) * -1;

                // draw drag view in max bottom position

                imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(ratio,0,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

            }

        }

        else if (image.size.width < image.size.height) // Height image

        {

            // after user pinch in the screen
            if (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.width)
            {

                // allow dragging only in X coordinates by only updating the X coordenates with translation position

                recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y);

                [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:imageViewForCrop];



                // get the top edge coordinate for the top left corner of crop frame

                float leftEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMinX(imageViewForCrop.frame);

                float leftEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMinX(cropErea.frame);



                //get the buttom edge coordinate for bottom left corner of crop frame

                float rightEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMaxX(imageViewForCrop.frame);

                float rightEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMaxX(cropErea.frame);

                //

                // if the top edge coordinate is less than or equal to Crop Erea frame

                if (leftEdgeImagePosition > leftEdgeCropEreaPosition)

                {

                    // draw drag view in max top position

                    imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(leftEdgeCropEreaPosition,imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

                }

                // if bottom edge coordinate is greater than or equal to 480

                if (rightEdgeImagePosition < rightEdgeCropEreaPosition)

                {

                    float ratio = (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width - cropErea.frame.size.width) * -1;

                    // draw drag view in max bottom position

                    imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(ratio,imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

                }




            }



            // allow dragging only in Y coordinates by only updating the Y coordenates with translation position

            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);



            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:imageViewForCrop];



            // get the top edge coordinate for the top left corner of crop frame

            float topEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMinY(imageViewForCrop.frame);

            float topEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMinY(cropErea.frame);



            //get the buttom edge coordinate for bottom left corner of crop frame

            float bottomEdgeImagePosition = CGRectGetMaxY(imageViewForCrop.frame);

            float bottomEdgeCropEreaPosition = CGRectGetMaxY(cropErea.frame);

            //

            // if the top edge coordinate is less than or equal to Crop Erea frame

            if (topEdgeImagePosition > topEdgeCropEreaPosition)

            {

                // draw drag view in max top position

                imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(0,topEdgeCropEreaPosition,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

            }

            // if bottom edge coordinate is greater than or equal to 480

            if (bottomEdgeImagePosition < bottomEdgeCropEreaPosition)

            {

                float ratio = (imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height - cropErea.frame.size.height) * -1;

                // draw drag view in max bottom position

                imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(0,ratio,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width,imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height);

            }


        }

        else

        {

            imageViewForCrop.frame = CGRectMake(cropErea.frame.origin.x, cropErea.frame.origin.y, 320, 320);

        }

    }

    default:

        break;

}

}
```

This is pinch method :

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
NSLog(@" X  %i " ,(int)imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x );

if ((int)imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x > 0 )
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [imageViewForCrop setFrame:CGRectMake( 0 , imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height )];
     }];




}

NSLog(@" Y  %i " , (int)imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y );

if ((int)imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y  > 0)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [imageViewForCrop setFrame:CGRectMake( imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x , 0 , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height )];
     }];






}

NSLog(@" Width  %i  and  %i " , (int)imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width , (int)originalSizeForIphoneWidth );

if ((int)imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width < (int)originalSizeForIphoneWidth)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [imageViewForCrop setFrame:CGRectMake( imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x , imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y , originalSizeForIphoneWidth+1, imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height)];
     }];





}

NSLog(@"Hight %i  and  %i " , (int)imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height , (int)originalSizeForIphoneHight );

if ((int)imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height <  (int)originalSizeForIphoneHight)
{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [imageViewForCrop setFrame:CGRectMake(imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x , imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width, originalSizeForIphoneHight+1)];
     }];



    //return;


    }


CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) pinchGestureRecognizer scale];
if(factor >1)
{
    // for the first time bug when pinch in or out
    if (lastScaleFactor == 0 )
    {
        lastScaleFactor = 1;
    }

    imageViewForCrop.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor +(factor-1), lastScaleFactor +(factor-1));
}
else // pinch in
{
    imageViewForCrop.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, lastScaleFactor*factor);


}


if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    if (factor>1) {
        lastScaleFactor +=(factor-1);
    }
    else {
        lastScaleFactor*= factor;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with limit maximumNumberOfTouches:

```
// handle Pan
  UIPanGestureRecognizer *panOnScreen = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panOnScreen.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[imageViewForCrop addGestureRecognizer:panOnScreen];
```

I hope this help someone (-: .